# Why my codes result 'module' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

I get an error while I wanted to change python random.sample array index. I would like to change my random.sample array index by increasing +1

```
x=0
randomarray = random.sample(range(1, len(codelist) - len(Genx1) - len(Genx2)), 3*len(s))

while (x < len(s)):
    randomarray.sort()
    print(randomarray)
    if ((codelist[randomarray[x]]=='B' ) and (s[x]=='A') or (codelist[randomarray[x]]=='A' ) and (s[x]=='B')):
        codelist[randomarray[x]] = s[x]
        x = x + 1
    else:
        random[x]= random[x]+1
        x = x
```

> > line 403, in ...
> >         random[x]= random[x]+1
> >     TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Did you mean `randomarray[x] ...`?  You've imported the `random` module, so you can't use that name for anything else.

Comment: Are you using `import random`? The list name and module name is same. Change list to something different

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your given code does not execute, for several reasons.

Comment: @Prune: Question looks like it meets those criteria to me...

Comment: Oh guys, I saw my mistake. As the Patrick said, I have to use 
         randomarray[x]

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you. I just did a very simple mistake. Now, I fixed, it works very well.

Comment: @martineau Satisfies the **Minimal** part only. Doesn't meet the **complete** part. Where is the `import random`? Doesn't meet the **verifiable** part. Do you get the same error if the code is run as is? (Answer: no!))

Comment: @VuralErdogan On a side note, do you have to `randomarray.sort()` inside the `while` loop over and over again? You are visiting every element of the `randomarray` list only once, and are either increasing the visited element by 1 or leaving it as is. The order is never altered, hence `sort` becomes redundant. Why not sort before the loop only once?

Comment: @robinCTS: Leaving out `import`s is common practice around here nowadays, so that's a non-issue which is also implied by the fact that the code has a `random.sample()` call in it and that the OP also obviously knows `random` is a module, hence the question title. Despite all that you're right in the sense that there no definition of `codelist` which results in a `NameError: name 'codelist' is not defined`.

Comment: @martineau You just contradicted your own first comment *"looks like it meets those criteria to me"* ;) And I was wrong about it satisfying the minimal part: from the [Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *"…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that **still produces the same problem**"*. Fundamentally, the code is not an MCVE because it is a snippet copy-and-pasted from the original source, as seen from the error message showing *"line403"* and `import random` / definition of `codelist` / etc being missing. If the supplied code cannot be copy-pasted and run to produce the identical…

Comment: …error supplied, then it is, by definition, not an MCVE. (Just because leaving out certain things is common practice, does not make it otherwise. Not even if in *most cases* the omissions are obvious and the answerability of the question is not impacted in any way.) As for the question title, it is simply quoting the error message. It cannot be used as evidence that the OP knows `random` is a module

Comment: @FatihAkici It is because the new value of randomarray[x] may exceed the next value of the array when I sum it with '+ 1'. For example; randomarray[x]= '39' and 'randomarray[x+1]='40'. When I sum it +1, and the condition is not provided again, it can be upgraded randomarray[x]='41'or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random` is the name of the module containing all of the random functions.  You tried to use it as if it were a list or array:

```
random[x] = random[x] + 1
```

`random[x]` is not a meaningful expression.  Also, `x = x` is a useless line of code -- it does nothing.